# How to create a graphics file in Java?

Tags: java, graphics

I need to create a 2D image file by simply setting colour of every point and then also output text at specific coordinates.

Can you recommend the easiest library for this and provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/2D/
Namely  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/2d/spec.html
Namely http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html

Example:

```
static final int X = 380, Y = 250;
static BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(X, Y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

static public void main(String[] args){

   WritableRaster wr = img.getRaster();

   int[] a = new int[3]; // 96 bit pixels
   a[0] = ...
   a[1] = ...
   a[2] = ...
   wr.setPixel(20, 20, a);

 }
```